# PHP | HTML - Debugging file uploader

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following code:

```
<?php
   if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_FILES ) ){
     ob_clean();


   /*
       process the uploaded files
       --------------------------

       check if there were errors
       check filesize
       check filetype
       check is_uploaded_file
       check if already exists
       etc
   */

   $output=array();
   $files=(object)$_FILES[ 'files' ];
   foreach( $files->name as $i => $void ){
        $name = $files->name[$i];
        $size = $files->size[$i];
        $type = $files->type[$i];
        $tmp  = $files->tmp_name[$i];
        $error= $files->error[$i];

        $output[]=array('name'=>$name,'size'=>$size,'type'=>$type);
    }
    exit( json_encode( $output ) );
 }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Browse multiple locations</title>
    <script>
        (function(){
            function ajax(url,payload,callback){
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if( this.readyState==4 && this.status==200 )callback.call( this, this.response );
                };
                xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
                xhr.send( payload );
            }


            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

                let fd=new FormData();

                const callback=function(r){
                    console.info( r )
                    let json=JSON.parse( r );
                    fd=new FormData();
                    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML=Object.keys( json ).length + ' files uploaded';
                };

                let oFile=document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
                let oBttn=document.querySelector('input[type="button"]');

                oFile.addEventListener( 'change', function(e){
                    for( var i=0; i < this.files.length; i++ ) fd.append( 'files[]', this.files[ i ], this.files[ i ].name );
                   document.getElementById('count').innerHTML=fd.getAll('files[]').length+' files in array';
               },false );




               oBttn.addEventListener( 'click', function(e){
                   if( fd.getAll('files[]').length > 0 ) ajax.call( this, location.href, fd, callback );
                },false );

            }, false );
        })();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div id='count'></div>
        <input type='file' name='files' multiple />
        <input type='button' value='Upload Files' />
    </form>
</body>
```

The purpose of the code should be to allow multiple uploads on a webpage, but from different directories. I.e. the upload process would go

> *browse* --> select file(s) --> *browse* --> select file(s) --> upload.

I understand the PHP and HTML code, but admit I dont have a good understanding of what the javascript is doing. I have googled a lot and have a good idea, but it is not thorough.

When I test my code using wamp server here is what happens:

1) I select $n$ files during a browse and the text displays "$n$ files added to the array", just as it should from looking at the javascript.

2) I browse again and select $m$ more files and the text displays "$n+m$ files added to the array" as it should.

3) I press upload and it displays "$n+m$ files uploaded, as desired from looking at the javascript". At this point if you have the console open in google chrome it shows the files that were uploaded.

My problem is that there seems to be a problem accessing the if statement at the beginning. I have added `echo "hello"` inside as a test  and it does not echo hello. I try `var_dump(_FILES['files'])` (edit: I meant `var_dump($_FILES['files'])` ) even outside of the if statement and it does not have all of the uploads (usually just the last one to be added or none). What is preventing me from processing my uploaded files? Where are the uploaded files going? How are they showing up in the console?

I am very new here, and new to programming. If there is anything I can do to improve the quality of my post, please let me know.

-------------EDIT-----------------

As I wonder if the `if` statement was being accessed, I did some testing. See here: https://pastebin.com/hEtte3MU

Only `hello 3` gets echoed back for me. ?

Edit: there was a typo in the first pastebin. Same issues with this one

https://pastebin.com/5Gka3UQH

Answer (score 0):

**Insted of writing echo "hello" write console.log("hello"); **

may

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
var_dump($_FILES['files']);
```

instead of:

```
var_dump(_FILES['files'])
```

OR you can handle it like this:

```
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){ echo 'there is a least one file'; }
```

Comment: Yeah, I did. Sorry - that was just a typo. Good spot though. Does it seem like the code should be working otherwise? As I mentioned I don't know the javascript and ajax stuff and am kinda new to webpage stuff so I can't figure out what might be interferring.

Comment: Then you want to validate if $_FILES is empty?

Comment: Try to remove the ] from this  'files]'

Comment: Check the pastebin I posted in my edit. I'm essentially trying to retrieve the files I uploaded. They are correctly showing up in the console when I click upload but I can't figure out how to get my hands on them with PHP so I can start using them on the page

Comment: I edited the post. take a look and don't forget to remove the ] from this 'files]'

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the issue here is with your `<form/>` tag, you will need the `enctype` attribute set in order to upload files...

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id='count'></div>
    <input type='file' name='files' multiple />
    <input type='button' value='Upload Files' />
</form>
```

Edit: looking back at the your code, the `enctype` must be specified in the js part that handles the upload, you will need to add :

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

before:

```
xhr.send( payload );
```

Comment: This was definitely one of the things I have tinkered with, because I read that somewhere, but I might have been trying multiple things at once. Let me isolate this attempt and report back

Comment: Weird, adding the second thing actually gave me an error in the console

Answer (score 0):

Spend some time to understand what AJAX is and how to use it with PHP and this will start to make sense. I will try to outline what is happening on your page and why you cannot see the output of your PHP but can see the latest files uploaded.

The JavaScript on your page is making individual `POST` requests each time you submit the form. The `POST` request is to the same URL as your current page, but it is an entirely separate request. Kind of like having two windows open of the same page. So `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` will not update on the page you are looking at, and you will never see the output of your tests.

What you should do is separate your `POST` logic to it's own file, and make your AJAX requests to that instead of including it all on one page. That will help you understand and maintain your code.

Comment: Is 'submitting the form' logically equivalent to clicking the "Upload Files" button?

Comment: Yes. It is the same, except it's being processed by an AJAX request.